# Best way to iterate through a numpy array returning the columns as 2d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

EDIT: Thank you all for the good solutions, I think if I'd had to pick one, it would be `A[:,[0]]`

I collected 7 approaches now and put them into an [IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/benchmarks/timeit_tests.ipynb?create=1#row_vectors). The timeit benchmarks are not suprising: they are all roughly the same in terms of speed.

Thanks a lot for your suggestion!

---

I a looking for a good way to iterate through the columns of a matrix and return them as 1xd column vectors. I have some ideas, but I don't think that those are good solutions. I think I am missing something here. Which way would you recommend? E.g., let's say I have the following matrix and want to return the first column as a column vector:

```
A = np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

By default, numpy returns it like this:

```
>>> A[:,0]
array([1, 4, 7])
>>> A[:,0].shape
(3,)
```

And what I want is this:

```
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
```

with `.shape` = (3,1)

---

Transpose doesn't work to return it as a column vector.

```
>>> A[:,0].T
array([1, 4, 7])

>>> A[:,0]
  array([1, 4, 7])
```

I would have to create a new axis every time

```
>>> A[:,0][:,np.newaxis].shape
(3, 1)
>>> A[:,0][:,np.newaxis]
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
```

Or after doing some experimenting, I came up with other workarounds like this:

```
>>> A[:,0:1]
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])

>>> A[:,0].reshape(A.shape[1],1)
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
```

Comment: Are you sure you need your extracts to be column vectors? If so, I think you have answered your question in your question: The canonical way to do this is to add a new axis. It is important to understand that this does not change the representation in memory. You seem to find it inconvenient. Why? Your workaround with `0:1` is OK as well, although it may be misleading for readers of your code who may think you are actually slicing bigger chunks.

Comment: Gotta ask why you need them as "column" vectors. How are you using the result?

Comment: There is virtually no cost to adding a `newaxis` or reshaping the result.

Comment: I thought there may be an easier way, e.g., like `for row in myarray:` something like `for col in myarray.cols` or so. Anyway, why I need them as columns? I feed them to functions which have asserts like myvec.shape[1] == 1

Comment: Iterate over the 'rows' of the transpose: `for col in A.T: print col.reshape(-1,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite solution is the slicing. You have different solutions :

```
A[:,0:1] # not so clear
A[:,:1]  # black magic
A[:,[0]] # clearest syntax imho
```

Concerning the `reshape` solution, you can enhance the syntax like this :

```
A[:,0].reshape(A.shape[1],1)
A[:,0].reshape(-1,1)
```

You can also merge the following :

```
A[:,0][:,np.newaxis] # ->
A[:,0,np.newaxis] # or
A[:,np.newaxis,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `numpy.row_stack` or `numpy.vstack`:

```
In [91]: np.row_stack(A[:,0])
Out[91]: 
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
In [92]: np.vstack(A[:,0])
Out[92]: 
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.column_stack((A[:,0],))
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
>>> #                ^^^^^^^ a tuple
```

Just make sure that you are feeding it a 1 element tuple for a single column or you are getting something different:

```
>>> np.column_stack(A[:,0])
array([[1, 4, 7]])
```